# Informatica Dynamic Folder Creation

Tags: transactions, mapping, etl, directory, informatica

My table consists of department data for over 15-20 clients and in my mapping, I am generating 10 different files based on the department type using transaction control which is working fine. The requirement is to generate these files for every client and place them in a separate folder for a respective client. Any idea on how I can go about achieving this? I know the mapping has to loop over all the clients and then create folders dynamically and place those ten files there, but I am a bit hung up on how to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a workflow variable and use it in Output File directory. Later you can assign a different value to workflow variable using assignment task. This way you can create Dynamic Folder using the same session.

OR

You can create all the files in one location and then write unix/batch script to read all the files from that location and move it to different folder as per your need.